# Php запись из БД в xml

Tags: xml, php, mysql

У меня есть база данных с картинками и текстом, как сделать так чтобы все данные из базы записались в xml файл, с помощью php скрипта может быть? Написал своими словами, надеюсь понятно выразился.

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Что-то не получается? Или нет идей как это сделать?

Xml, по сути, - это обычный файл, почему не писать в него готовые куски данных? Главное, чтобы эти куски были частью валидного xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {printf("Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit;}

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom -> encoding = "windows-1251";
$root = $dom->createElement('list');
$root = $dom->appendChild($root);

$offers = $dom->createElement('offers');
$offers = $root->appendChild($offers);

/* Посылаем запрос серверу */

if ($result = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * from table    ")) 
{while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
```

/ *Выбираем результаты запроса:* /

```
$url_offer=$row['url'];

$offer = $dom->createElement('offer');
$url = $dom->createElement('url');
$text = $dom->createTextNode($url_offer);
$url->appendChild($text);
$offer->appendChild($url);
```

} # end while
$result->close();

/ *Освобождаем память* /

} #end  out sql query 
$mysqli->close();

/ *Закрываем соединение* /

$fp = fopen( "rr.xml", "w" );
fputs( $fp, $dom->saveXML() );
fclose( $fp );